# Storing string value to array

Tags: objective-c

I am new to iOS developing. I am building a sample project where I have a textfield. I have stored the textfield text into a string. Now I want to show that data to a table view cell in a new view controller. Can anyone tell me what will be the code to store the string data into an array?

Comment: from your question, i couldn't understand what do you want to do? set all the text into one index? or every word in each index? please clarify you question

Comment: Set all the text into one index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ArrayLinks](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsarray)

Basically, you need to have a `NSMutableArray` and then you can call

```
NSString *string = @"";
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray new]; // create the array
[arr addObject:string];
```

If you want to add it in another viewController then you need to pass the String object to the "other ViewController" using the

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

or Delegation, KVO... (but this topics are more advanced for you)

Answer (score 0):

Set UITextFieldDelegate in your ViewController. It will catch(recognize) your input.

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

ViewController.m

```
@interface ViewController()
{
    NSMutableArray *inputs;
}    

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // initailize Array
    inputs = [NSMutableArray array];
    // delegate 
    self.yourTextField.delegate = self;
}

#pragma mark - TextField Delegate

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField 
{
    // get your text in delegated textfield
    NSString *inputStr = textField.text;
    // add text to the array
    [self.inputs addObject: inputStr];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This appears to have nothing to do with the question.

Comment: This shows a very simple example controller that on a textfield delegate stores the input of the textfield in an array. Which seems to answer the first part of the question.